# C# How to put RadioButton inside Panel

Tags: c#

I have searched everywhere, but the procedure are so painful. How to put multiple RadioButton into a panel programatically without using toolbox. I'm using WinForms. After several suggestion/s, I still can't add the radiobuttons inside the panel.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    RadioButton[] RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes = new RadioButton[100];
    RadioButton[] RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No = new RadioButton[100];

    Panel[] Panel_WallFirstStorey = new Panel[100];

    int CheckBoxWidth = 100;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //code
        //procedure
    }

    private void InitializeRadioButton_Wall(RadioButton RadioButtonX)
    {
        RadioButtonX.AutoSize = true;
        RadioButtonX.Font = SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
        RadioButtonX.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        Controls.Add(RadioButtonX);
    }

    private void InitializePanel_Wall(Panel PanelX)
    {
        PanelX.BackColor = Color.PaleTurquoise;
        PanelX.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        PanelX.BringToFront();
        Controls.Add(PanelX);
    }

    private void MyProcedure()
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            Panel_WallFirstStorey[i] = new Panel();
            InitializePanel_Wall(Panel_WallFirstStorey[i]);
            Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Location = new Point(Label_SeparatorLineVertical[ColumnMinimum + i].Location.X, Label_SeparatorLineHorizontal[RowMinimum + i].Location.Y);
            Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Width = (Label_SeparatorLineVertical[ColumnMaximum].Location.X - Label_SeparatorLineVertical[ColumnMinimum].Location.X) / (ColumnMaximum - ColumnMinimum);
            Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Height = CheckBoxWidth;
            Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].SendToBack();
        }

        for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i] = new RadioButton();
            RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i] = new RadioButton();

            Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Controls.Add(RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i]);//I add this stuff
            Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Controls.Add(RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i]);//I add this stuff

            InitializeRadioButton_Wall(RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i]);
            InitializeRadioButton_Wall(RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i]);

            RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i].Text = "Yes";
            RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i].Text = "No";

            RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i].Location = new Point(Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Width / 3, 0);
            RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i].Location = new Point(Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Width * 2 / 3, 0);

            RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i].Font = SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
            RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i].Font = SystemFonts.DefaultFont;

            RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i].BringToFront();
            RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i].BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do refer to radioButtons for WPF?

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: are you talking about winforms or WPF. please edit you tags.

Comment: Why not use `RadioButtonList` ?

Comment: you mean you want to create panel and then create radiobutton(s) and then add the readio buttons inside panel.. All this stuff from code behind. right?

Comment: This work for me `panel1.Controls.Add(new RadioButton {Text = "button1",Top = 0});
            panel1.Controls.Add(new RadioButton { Text = "button2", Top = 20 });
            panel1.Controls.Add(new RadioButton { Text = "button3", Top = 40 });`

Comment: I post here my code but it doesn't work..  Only the last RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[100] is working.

Comment: Your mistake is using `Paint` event, do it on form `Load` or in constructor

Comment: @ShubhamBhave Yes you're absolutely right

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, i said **form** `Load`, he wants to programmaticaly add `RadioButtons` as alternative `DesignTime` so he has to use some events. *"Use event"* doesn't means write all stuf in event handler body, don't eat words

Comment: @agent5566 I misread your comment. I thought you suggested that instead of putting the code into the `Paint` event of the control he should put it in the `Load` event of the control. Sorry to interrupt.

Comment: @SonGozita Your code is still wrong. Did you even *read* all the answers or understand what people are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, your code is wrong in so many ways.... It creates controls over and over whenever a panel is *painted*, but it never really adds them anywere.

To add a radio button `b` to a panel `p`, it would be enough to do this:

```
RadioButton b = new RadioButton();
// Set properties for button here (text, location, handlers, etc.)

p.Controls.Add(b);
```

---

I'd try the following procedure instead of yours:

```
private void MyProcedure() 
{
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i] = new RadioButton();
        RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i] = new RadioButton();
        InitializeRadioButton_Wall(RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i]);
        InitializeRadioButton_Wall(RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i]);

        RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i].Text = "Yes";
        RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i].Text = "No";

        RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i].Location = new Point(Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Location.X + Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Width / 3, Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Location.Y);
        RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i].Location = new Point(Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Location.X + Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Width * 2 / 3, Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Location.Y);

        Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Controls.Add(RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i]);
        Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Controls.Add(RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i]);
    }
}
```

---

The following code indicates you're still doing it wrong, adding the radio buttons to the form itself, but *positioning* them *as if you had added them* to the panel:

```
RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i].Location = new Point(Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Location.X + Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Width / 3, Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Location.Y);
```

If you added the button to the panel, it would most probably be invisible because it is outside the panel. If you added the button to the panel, you'd have to use coordinates relative to the panel's client area.

```
RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i].Location = new Point(Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Width / 3, 0);
RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i].Location = new Point(Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Width * 2 / 3, 0);
```

---

Your update code shows clearly where your error is:

```
private void InitializeRadioButton_Wall(RadioButton RadioButtonX)
{
    RadioButtonX.AutoSize = true;
    RadioButtonX.Font = SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
    RadioButtonX.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

    // REMOVE THIS LINE!!
    Controls.Add(RadioButtonX);
}
```

The last line adds the radio button **to the form**. As we've been telling you all the time. Remove the line I marked above. Then, the radio buttons will be added to the panels **only**. After that it is a question of getting the positions right.

Comment: Thanks..it actually works as you suggested. I have 200radiobuttons. But the problem is, when i clicked radiobutton in panel1, then i clicked the panel2, panel1 is unclicked/unselected. I need at least one enable radiobutton in each panel

Comment: Hm, that should actually be handled by adding them to different panels. Are you sure the buttons are added to different panels now? Maybe check the change to my answer I made showing how I'd implement your code.

Comment: Yes it's in right position in the panel.. I put your code  "Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Controls.Add(RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_Yes[i]);        Panel_WallFirstStorey[i].Controls.Add(RadioButton_WallFirstStorey_No[i]); " before initializeradiobutton.. the problem is i can select one radiobutton at a time

Comment: As I said, the fact that the radio buttons are in different panels should take care of allowing you to select one per panel instead of one per form.

Comment: Wait a second. In your code you set the position of the radio button to be the left corner of the panel + some value. That would not work if you added the radio button to your panel, as most probably the radio button would be placed outside the panel and be invisible! That code is only necessary if you add the radio button to the form but *position it to look* like it was added to the panel. Please make sure the buttons are in fact added to a panel, and NOT to the FORM! Change the location to be relative to the panel!

Comment: Yes you are right, when i deleted the position in my code relative to the panel. The RadioButtons are outside in the Panel.. And only few of button are visible

Comment: it still outside of the panel. but the location along x axis are correct, but the y location is wrong

Comment: Do you even *read* what people are telling you? a) post all relevant code, b) **you are adding to the form, not a panel**, c) the code in your question is still wrong!!

Comment: i post my updated but summarized code.. i understand some but not all and I tried all of the suggestion.. I really don't know how to correct this kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

You can for example create a panel (or a GroupBox) and in a loop add the RadioButtons.

It should work like with any other control in Winforms.

```
    // Adds 10 Radiobuttons with the name "Radio <number>" 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
        {
            // First instantiate a new RadioButton.
            RadioButton button = new RadioButton();

            // Now the name of the button.
            button.Text = "Radio" + n;

            // Dock the button to the top of the GroupBox (to put them in order)
            button.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

            // Add the button to the GroupBox.
            this.groupBoxRadio.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it didn't work either.. the radio button now located at the top left of the screen

Comment: Then you didn't add to a panel or group box, but to the form.

Comment: Yes because you dock it. If you dont want to dock the radio button you have to create a method that finds the Location you need.

Comment: That would also explain why you need to set the radio button location in absolute coordinates (location of panel + some value) instead of relative to the panel's client area. You're adding to the form, not the panel.

Comment: @SonGozita Do you read what people are saying? **You are not adding the buttons to a panel, but to the form**!

Comment: @ElMac Thanks for the hint. SO f**ked it up by adding an additional http://. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, and no code for context, but you should be able to create an instance of a new radiobutton and add it to the controls of the panel.

It may also be best to use `RadioButtonList` like Harvey has mentioned, but to try to answer your question:

```
var someRadioBtn = new RadioButton();
// set properties...

pnlMyPanel.Controls.Add(someRadioBtn);
```